# Unable to receive UDP packets

Tags: c#, .net, networking, udp

I'm attempting to send and receive UDP packets from the same machine using two separate programs but so far I've not been able to receive anything. I've attempted completely turning off my firewall and that still hasn't worked.

Sending program

```
var sender = new UdpClient(Dns.GetHostName(), 2055);

var data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
sender.Send(data, data.Length);
```

Receiving program

```
var receiver = new UdpClient(2055);

var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2055);
var data = receiver.Receive(ref endPoint);
System.Console.WriteLine("Data received");
```

I've even copy and pasted code from this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using and still had no success.

Comment: What is `Dns.GetHostName()`? Should not it be `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Ah, this worked! Could you post an answer (so that I can select it as the solution) and explain a little about why this works and not Dns.GetHostName()? I was using GetHostName() fine with a TCP connection on the same machine.

Comment: Sure, glad we were able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `var sender = new UdpClient(Dns.GetHostName(), 2055);`

You need to specify your local host IP which is `127.0.0.1` since you are on the same machine. This should work:

`var sender = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", 2055);`

Answer (score 0):

From [About multicast IP addresses and ports (TechNet)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730839(v=ws.10).aspx):

> **Multicast IP addresses are class-D addresses that fall within two ranges: 224.0.0.0 through 239.255.255.255** and FF00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 through FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF. The addresses in the first range are Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) addresses. The addresses in the second range are Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) addresses.
>
> For intranet use, it is recommended that you use IPv4 addresses in the range 239.*.*.*. Port numbers can range between 1 and 65535. The routers on the network over which you are transmitting your content must be multicast-enabled, meaning that they must be able to interpret class-D addresses or they will not be able to forward your multicast information to clients.

You have to use an IP address in this range because of network-level filtering. There's a table of [commonly-used multicast addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#IPv4) on Wikipedia.

Actually, the tutorial you're using notes this too:

> UDP also supports multicasting i.e. sending a single datagram to multiple receivers. To do so, the sender sends a packet to an IP address in the range 224.0.0.1 – 239.255.255.255 (Class D address group).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how this works with my problem of sending/receiving on the same machine, especially since using the local host address fixes the problem.